# What's the best way to secure helmet straps?

Tags: road-bike, safety, helmets

On every helmet I've worn there is always some extra length to the straps that run through the buckle that secures the helmet to ones head.  Most helmet's these days come with one or two small rubber rings or something similar in which to loop the extra length on the strap.

Is there a better way to do this than the ways I've tried?  The most obvious way is to simply cut the slack off but I'm not really after that.  I'd like to see how others finish their helmet straps to be the most comfortable around the neck and the least intrusive.  Below are pictures of:

unfinished straps

method 1

method 2

I've been riding with method 1 and method 2 for awhile.  Is there a better way to secure the straps other than cutting?

[image: unfinished]

[image: method 1]

[image]

Comment: When cutting, don't forget to melt the end of each strap with a lighter. Personally I ride method 1 with cut end.

Comment: I guess my OCD wasn't advanced enough for me to care, but now that you've got me thinking about it I'm sure I soon will.

Comment: Melting/burning the ends prevents the strap from fraying and it looks almost at good as it was from the factory.

Comment: I just leave it as is. In winter this is useful since i wear a balaclava or wool cap to prevent my head from freezing, and this requires a bit more strap. And it never really bothered me anyway...

Comment: Mine looks like pic #2 but I've been thinking of #3 and putting a narrow strip of duct-tape around the folded strand.

Comment: Mine start like #2, then at some point I'm on a fast downhill and the loose ends are flapping about and slapping me in the ear and neck.  At that point I might use a finger to shove the loose ends under the strap beside my chin, but more often I need both hands for the descent so simply hunch down or tilt my head a bit.  Is worst on cold descents.

Comment: I've never gotten round to trimming the straps. I just wind the loose end around the chin strap under my chin a couple of times before I set off. A Fermi estimate is that this wastes about an hour of my life per year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the advice of those who commented: I came upon this solution.

1. Cut the access length (about 1 cm), leaving enough for adjustment
2. Melt the ends of the straps with a torch
3. Use electrical tape to wrap the ends tightly so they resemble 'method 1' but without the excess length.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I sewed them on, using around four stitches.

Now they are as secure as glue.